# Error when connecting mysql database with node js

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, json, ajax

I am using Node JS and I am trying to connect to a mysql database. It keeps getting disconnected.When I run npm start,error shows as follows

> D:\face-api.js\face-api.js\examples\FaceLogInBackend\app.js:26
>   app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
>       ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
>   at Object. (D:\face-api.js\face-api.js\examples\FaceLogInBackend\app.js:26:5)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)

Code in app.js is as belows

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'bookstore' 

});

connection.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err
console.log('You are now connected...')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');

// instead of storing the result in a variable, just make the connection,
mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'bookstore' 
});

// now connect to mysql
mysql.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('You are now connected...')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First off check you have something like this declared on top of file

```
var app = express();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to connect to the MySQL. It works fine.

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


const mysql = require('mysql');
// connection configurations
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'bookstore' 
});

// connect to database
connection.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err
console.log('You are now connected...')
})

app.listen(port);

console.log('API server started on: ' + port);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```